# Prove that $\lfloor a\rfloor + \lfloor a+0.5\rfloor =\lfloor 2a\rfloor $ for every real number $a$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that: $$\lfloor a\rfloor + \lfloor a+0.5\rfloor =\lfloor 2a\rfloor $$ for every real number $a$

I know that you can say that $a=\lfloor a\rfloor+\phi$ with $0\leq \phi<1$. Please help.

Comment: Note: I reformatted your post to correct a typo and to  use the more standard notation for the greatest integer function. (see, e.g., [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions))  Please check to make sure I didn't change your intent.

Comment: Worth noting:   Where the floor $\lfloor a \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer $≤a$ we could also speak of the ceiling $\lceil a \rceil$, the least integer $≥a$.  It's also standard to denote by $\{a\}$ the fractional part of $a$, that is $\{a\}=a-\lfloor a \rfloor$, which you call $\phi$ in your post.

Answer (score 4):

Write $a= k+\phi$ where $0\leq \phi<1$ and $k=[a]$. Now consider two cases.

- If  $\phi <1/2$ then $$\lfloor a\rfloor + \lfloor a+0.5\rfloor = k+\lfloor k+\phi+0.5\rfloor = 2k+\lfloor\phi+0.5\rfloor=2k =2\lfloor a\rfloor$$
- $\phi \geq 1/2$ then $$\lfloor a\rfloor + \lfloor a+0.5\rfloor = k+\lfloor k+\phi+0.5\rfloor = 2k+\lfloor\phi+0.5\rfloor=2k +1$$
  on the other hand we have also
  $$\lfloor 2a\rfloor=\lfloor 2k+2\phi\rfloor =2k+\lfloor2\phi\rfloor =2k+1$$
  where $\lfloor2\phi\rfloor=1$

and we are done.